# ApolloError: Invariant: Method expects to have requestAsyncStorage, none available

Tags: next.js, graphql, apollo, next-auth

I have a Next.js project where I use next-auth for authorization.

**explain the situation:**

I have a list of users, so when I click on the card it sends the request to the server with setContext, which passes a user token for every request, but I got such an error:

```
ApolloError: Invariant: Method expects to have requestAsyncStorage, none available
```

but when I fetch users from the server there are no problems, and the token works fine.

**What did I try?:**

I wasted a lot of time trying to find an answer, but none of the answers helped me.

also, I tried to remove "getServerSession" and I manually set the token in the setContext header, and it started working fine without error.

so finally I think the problem is in "getServerSession", but how I can get a token from the cookie?

"getSession" is not a server-side function so it gives me nothing.

**resource:**

so, here is an "apollo-client.ts" code, where I use "setContext"

```
const wsLink =
  typeof window !== "undefined"
    ? new GraphQLWsLink(
        createClient({
          url: "ws://localhost:5000/subscriptions",
        })
      )
    : null;

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:5000/",
  credentials: "same-origin",
});

const link =
  typeof window !== "undefined" && wsLink != null
    ? split(
        ({ query }) => {
          const def = getMainDefinition(query);
          return (
            def.kind === "OperationDefinition" &&
            def.operation === "subscription"
          );
        },
        wsLink,
        httpLink
      )
    : httpLink;

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  return getServerSession(authOptions).then((el) => {
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: el ? `Bearer ${el?.accessToken}` : "",
      },
    };
  });
});

const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(link),
  cache: cache,
  uri: "http://localhost:5000/",
  credentials: "include",
});

export default client;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your client, links etc, in global module scope - that means you create one instance of ApolloClient that will be shared between all users and requests your server sees. When using a SSR framework like Next.js, you should never do that.

That's also the reason you are seeing this error - `getServerSession` wants to access the current request, but you are calling it in a context outside of any request.

Instead, create a function that creates a new Apollo Client, and create a new instance for every request by calling it. Pretty much every "Apollo Client and Next.js" guide you can find out there should show that pattern.

You cannot apply the client-side-only pattern of a module-scope Apollo Client instance with Next.js.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand what you are saying, but can you give me some pointers? Where I can read the code.

Comment: You could take a look at https://github.com/apollographql/next-apollo-example for code, but I can't recommend you a good tutorial since I don't know one. But literally every tutorial out there that is specific to next.js, Apollo Client and the pages router (I think you're still using that?) should contain the right patterns. Just don't go for any "only Apollo Client" tutorials, you need something explicitly for Next.js with the router you use, because Next.js adds a lot of patterns on top.